# Display Ad every after 3 Posts

Tags: wordpress, ads

I'm trying to display an advertisement every after 3 posts in a wordpress blog. Could you guys check something that's wrong in the code?

See the code [here](http://pastebin.com/2GNUWBSf)

Comment: Did you change the `x` to `3;`?

Answer (score 0):

see Make $after_every = 0 and add $after_every++ bottom of while loop

then add one condition

```
if($after_every%3==0){ Show add}
```

I think it works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why are you using modulus there.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

I think that is something you didn't want. 
The way I usualy do this is:

```
if( $ad_counter >= 3 ) {
$ad_counter = 0;
echo '<h2 style="color:red;">Advertisement or custom content here</h2>';
}
```

And you can remove line 12 :)